# Problems minimizing a two variable function with "scipy.optimize.brute"

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization, scipy-optimize

I'm trying to minimize a function of two variables using `scipy.optimize.brute` algorithm, but I've receiving the error `TypeError: Fcone() missing 1 required positional argument: 'R'`.

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt

gamma = 17.
C = 45.
T = 12.
H = 1.2
R = 1.3
H1 = 0.57

def Fcone(alpha, beta, H1, gamma, C, T, H, R):
    return np.pi/((np.cos(alpha))**2 * (np.cos(beta))**2) * ((np.cos(alpha))**2 
             * ((np.cos(beta))**2 * (gamma*H1**3 + 2*H1**2*(C-T-gamma*H) - H*H1*
                    (2*C-2*T-gamma*H) + H*(gamma*R**2 + H*(C-T)-(gamma*H**2)/3)) -
                2*R*(H-H1)*np.cos(beta) * ((gamma*H1/2 - gamma*H/2 + C -T)*
                    np.sin(beta) - C) + (C*np.sin(beta) + gamma*H/3 - gamma*H1/3 
                        -C + T)*(H-H1)**2) - 2*H1*np.cos(beta)*np.cos(alpha)*(
                        R*np.cos(beta)*((gamma*H1/2 + C -T -gamma*H)*np.sin(alpha)
                    - C) + np.sin(alpha)*(H-H1)*((gamma*H1/2 - gamma*H/2 + C -T)
                                *np.sin(beta)-C)) + (np.cos(beta))**2 * H1**2 *
                                                 (gamma*H + C*np.sin(alpha) 
                                                  -2*gamma*H1/3 -C+T))

ranges = (slice(0, np.pi/2, np.pi/10000), slice(0, np.pi/2, np.pi/10000))
res = opt.brute(Fcone, ranges, args=(H1, gamma, C, T, H, R), finish=None)
```

Where gamma, C,T, H, R1 and H1 are given parameters. Despite the very large (and probably confusing equation), how can I fix this problem and minimize the function for the two parameters alpha and beta? Thank you!

P.S.: The function alone is running fine when I assign all values for the parameters.

Comment: There is a mismatch between the arguments of `Fcone` and `args`. The **core assumption** everywhere in `scipy.optimize` is, that the first argument is `x`, a vector of *all your variables*. If you got two, namely *alpha* and *beta*, you will need a vector of size two. Not two arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amend `Fcone()` as follows...

```
def Fcone(alpha_beta, H1, gamma, C, T, H, R):
    alpha = alpha_beta[0]
    beta  = alpha_beta[1]
    .....
```

The variables being optimized have to be put into a 1D array, [check docs here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brute.html). Their values will be in `res[0]`